# Property of Covariance Matrices and Symmetric Matrices

Tags: covariance-matrix, linear-algebra

I have a question about covariance matrices. I have read one interesting property that, all symmetric matrices are diagonalizable.

Suppose we have a data matrix $X$ that has only $m$ independent columns. Additionally, the corresponding covariance matrix $$\Sigma = (X - \mu)^T(X -\mu)$$

My question is, say the covariance matrix, $\Sigma$, lives in $R^{p *p}$, but this matrix will only have $m$ independent columns. Does this imply that we still get $p$ (full) orthogonal eigenvectors or only $m$ orthogonal eigenvectors and the remaining $p - m$ independent but not orthogonal eigenvectors?

Comment: For a symmetric matrix with $p$ rows and columns, you can always find $p$ orthogonal eigenvalues [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82467/eigenvectors-of-real-symmetric-matrices-are-orthogonal).

Comment: For some intuition, consider the case $m=0.$